# How to secure bookcase to drywall right over concrete without drilling concrete?

Tags: drywall, concrete, installation, anchor

I got some tall bookcases and want to set them up against a wall in a condo.
The wall is shared with my neighbor and as such it seems to be a half inch drywall right over a concrete wall, so I don't have space to secure toggle bolts or other drywall anchors.

Technically I'm not allowed to alter the common concrete wall so I want to avoid drilling into the concrete to secure it that way (no hammer drill or masonry bits anyways).

As per this picture the book case will fit on the right under the bulkhead, is there anything I can do with that?

[image]

Comment: could it be secured to the floor and ceiling instead?

Comment: That bulkhead space is going to contain some utility lines, likely HVAC ducts, but possibly plumbing. Make sure you're screwing into some structure up there, and not damaging a utility line. Also note that bulkheads are often built poorly and may fail when exposed to a load it wasn't designed to handle.

Answer (score 2):

I think you already hit on it. The bulk head at the top would be a good place to secure the book shelf from tipping. Set the book shelf in place and then angle bracket the structure to the ceiling so it won't tip. Find a stud or other structure at the ceiling to make it sound.

If the book shelf does not stand as tall as the ceiling, then you have another aspect than needs attention. Think outside the box. Can you frame in an addition to the existing, what, a duct? Just think that you won't need extreme support for the bookshelf if you have good connections to the ceiling. For example, if you stand the bookshelf on it's own, how hard is it to tip over? Now think if you screw that to the ceiling, how hard would it be to tip over? If you have kids, or even if you don't, make sure it's secure.